# Xcode 6.1 can not recognize NSUserDefault

Tags: xcode6

I try to input NSUserDefault in Xcode6.1, it does not be recognized. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no image, but have you imported the Foundation framework? Place this at the top of your file:

```
import Foundation
```